# Delete a row with duplicate field value but keep the later one in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am pretty new to MySql and I want to run a query and delete the record of duplicate product_id and keep the latest one

**id**     **rule_id**       **produc_id** 
6        3               2 
7        3               3 
8        4               2  
9        4               5  
10       4              9

This my table and I want to delete the record of **id=6** because the product_id here, is repeated again in **id=8** but I want to keep the record of **id=8**...

Also, the query should be flexible enough so that if I add another record in the table with repetitive product_id again then the query should delete the record with **id=8** and keep the latest record...
Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0):

```sql
DELETE t1
FROM table t1
JOIN table t2 USING (produc_id)
WHERE t1.id < t2.id
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=2c2724a7b82bc78e7f6ecbaeeeabc2f6